# Rails, expire cookies after logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

It is possible to expire cookies automatically when the user logouts? Or it should be done manually? If manually, how can I get a list of all cookies I have during a session? (I know the names of all my cookies but I do not want to explicitly set every cookie to nil manually)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly - no. Rails its a pretty web framework. You needn't worry anything, only for business logic. 
Read [off docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#replay-attacks-for-cookiestore-sessions) about security for more details.